# Error while hosting CanvasLMS-encryption key is incorrect if you have intentionally changed it you may want to run rake db:reset_encryption_key_hash

Tags: ubuntu, canvas-lms

I have been working on hosting canvas lms on the Ubuntu server manually. I have been following the wiki page - Production Start. After resolving all the errors, I successfully executed all the steps. But when I opened the browser to access the application using IP address/ hostname, I got the below webpage:

[image]

When I accessed the log file at path /var/log/apache2/error.log, I got the following error:
Could not spawn process for application /var/canvas: The application encountered the following error: encryption key is incorrect. if you have intentionally changed it, you may want to run rake db:reset_encryption_key_hash (SystemExit)

I tried the following commands/ways to resolve this error:

```
bundle exec rake db:reset_encryption_key_hash
rake db:reset_encryption_key_hash
bundle exec rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production
rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production
bundle exec rake db:generate_security_key
Updated encryption key in security.yml file, removed the encryption key
```

Still, there was no luck, can anyone help me with this?